# Close windows session and power off computer from winform application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I would like to close my windows session and power off the computer directly from my winform c# application.

I've looked for ways to do that but I only find event handlers of these actions in .NET documentation. I might be missing something. Could you please light it up for me ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do this directly from managed code, but you can do it through P/Invoke. See https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/InitiateShutdown.html

Comment: I don't quite understand how to use what's in this doc..

Comment: P/Invoke is a way to invoke native code from C# as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke. Once you understand that, the linked info should be helpful with the specifics. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to shutdown your computer by an windows forms application so you can use the shutdown.exe file.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
Process.Start("C:\\Windows\\System32\\shutdown.exe", "-s - t 0");
```